# How to translate the tensor type into numpy type?

Tags: python, pytorch

```
import torch
x = torch.linspace(-5, 5, 200)
x_np = x.numpy()
```

it return:

```
UserWarning: Failed to initialize NumPy: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' (Triggered internally at  ..\torch\csrc\utils\tensor_numpy.cpp:68.)
  _dtype_to_storage = {data_type(0).dtype: data_type for data_type in _storages}
RuntimeError: Numpy is not available
```

environment；
python3.7
pytorch==1.10.2

Comment: can you check what is your `numpy` version in your environment?

Comment: I upgrade it and now it is numpy==1.21.5.
now I solve my problem.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need numpy installed

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you. I follow your suggestions and I solve it.